# Compare two different arrays and unset element from the first one

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

Hey guys. I have a question.
I have two different arrays with different structure and i want to compare the values and unset the common values.
The first arrays looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [key1] => value1 [key2] => value2 ) [1] => Array ( [key1] => value3 [key2] => value4 ) [2] => Array ( [key1] => value5 [key2] => value6 ) [3] => Array ( [key1] => value7 [key2] => value9 ) [4] => Array ( [key1] => value11 [key2] => value13 ))
```

The second array looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => value1 [1] => value3 [2] => value9)
```

So, i need to parse all the values from the first array and compare the first key with elements from the second array.
Something like this

```
foreach($array1 as $ar1){
    foreach($array2 as $ar2){
        if($ar1['key1'] == $ar2){
            unset($array1[$ar1]);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried everything but it's not working. The first array is generated so i can't change it's structure. The second one is made by hand.
After the process, the first array will look like:

```
 Array ([2] => Array ( [key1] => value5 [key2] => value6 ) [3] => Array ( [key1] => value7 [key2] => value8 ))
```

Help me with some ideas.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($array1 as $k => $ar1){
    foreach($array2 as $ar2){
        if($ar1['key1'] == $ar2){
            unset($array1[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```